# C function inputs are somehow taking the same memory in address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, dereference

I've been staring at this problem for a while and I can't seem to find an obvious solution nor the vocabulary to describe the specific issue. I'll try my best:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char** findWords(char** words, int wordsSize, int* returnSize) {

    *returnSize = 15; //<- wordsSize and returnSize have the same memory address????

    printf("wordsSize is %d\n", wordsSize);
    for(int i=0; i<wordsSize; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d first word: %s, len: %d\n", i, words[i], strlen(words[i]));
    }
}

int main(void){
    char **test; // this should be const char but func decl is predefined

    test[0] = "Hello";
    test[1] = "Alaska";
    test[2] = "Dad";
    test[3] = "Peace";


    int *foo;

    findWords(test, 4, foo);

    printf("%d", *foo);

}
```

When findWords() gets called, I see that &wordsSize and *returnSize are the same (i.e. they have the same memory address)

```
[New Thread 3492.0x9d0]

Breakpoint 1, findWords (words=0x7efde000, wordsSize=4, returnSize=0x28ff24) at keyboardrow.c:15
15          printf("wordsSize is %d\n", wordsSize);
(gdb) print &wordsSize
$1 = (int *) 0x28ff24
(gdb) print returnSize
$2 = (int *) 0x28ff24
(gdb)
```

Am I missing something obvious? It seems to me that &wordsSize and returnSize should have different memory addresses since they are two separate variables.

Comment: The behavior of your program is undefined. You didn't initialize `test` so what is it pointing at for you to assign at `test[0]`?

Comment: You want to find and read a good C book. You also want to look at the warnings your compiler is giving you. Not doing this == wasting your time. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` to your compilation flags.

Comment: Thanks, I'm re-reading K&R2, and I've added those flags - it raised a: 'test' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
  test[0] = "Hello";

Answer (score 2):

```
char **test; // this should be const char but func decl is predefined

test[0] = "Hello";
test[1] = "Alaska";
test[2] = "Dad";
test[3] = "Peace";
```

You can't do what you are doing above. `test` doesn't point to any "meaningful" place.

Comment: It points somewhere for sure, just we can't be sure about the "where" part. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, sure

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
test[0] = "Hello";
test[1] = "Alaska";
test[2] = "Dad";
test[3] = "Peace";
```

all of these invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as `test`, on it's own does not point to a *valid* memory.

Before you can dereference `test` to obtain `test[n]`, you need to make sure that `test` is pointed to a valid memory which is having enough size to make the `test[n]` access a valid one.

Instead of the above snippet, you can simple write

```
 char * test[] = { "Hello", "Alaska", "Dad", "Peace" };
```

and get done with it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this alone could mess with other portions of the code so significantly. The function call is expecting char** words unfortunately :\ [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/keyboard-row/#/description)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding it, the expected format is 
char** findWords(char** words, int wordsSize, int* returnSize) {} - I am forced to use that function declaration.

Comment: @jaytielle what do you mean "forced"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking undefined behavior by calling a pointer that doesn't point to anywhere, various variables/ pointers may point to same memory address, just like in situations where different variables may contain the same garbage value!